# MacBook Air fails to wake from suspend

Tags: display, suspend

I've got loki installed on a MacBook Air.  Is there a **reliable** way to ensure that the display wakes again after suspend?  I generally just close my laptop when I'm done with it (like, I guess 99.9999% of laptop users) so that I can pick up where I left off easily.

I am using the open source drivers, because the Nvidia drivers give me a black screen - this has been long a problem with nvidia and noveau.  I don't do any gaming or graphics-intensive work on this, so I'm happy enough to continue to use noveau.